# FAQ is missing the meaning of "on hold". Should that be added?

Tags: discussion, on-hold, documentation

Under the topic:
**Working with posts**

In the list:
**What does it mean when a question is...**
closed?
locked?
deleted?
protected?

The status [on hold] is missing.

Should this be added?

There is a high ranked link at: [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)

Comment: For meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions or for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: We've got a bit of a schizophrenia going on in the UI concerning whether it is called "closed" or "on hold". Note that the phrasing "on hold" is quite new, a bit nicer phrasing for our old use of "closed".

Comment: Ahhh... Closed sounds like "closed forever" whereas On Hold sounds like "fix your crappy post"

Comment: @Dhorse exactly!

Comment: Hmmm.  Even I could make that edit.  I'll see if it will let me.

Comment: The [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/152859) is under our (ordinary users) control, it's our responsibility to edit it.

Comment: @DHorse no need, I've just added it myself. :)

Comment: OK. BTW I entered FAQ in the search text in the help center and didn't see the FAQ link.  Curious.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  Should I now delete this post?

Comment: @DHorse no, let it be no harm done and it gave you some rep.